Magento 2.4 frontend does not load properly
Has it ever happened to you that for some reason the frontend of your Magento ecommerce does not load correctly? I have created several ecommerce sites but I am currently in a hurry and everything is "installed" correctly but when I access the frontend it does not load correctly, I compiled the frontend but nothing loads. If this has happened to anyone, I hope you can give me a hand.

Please provide additional information such as Browser errors log, PHP exceptions, Magento logs.

have you checked the logs? have u verified in apache2 or nginx logs?

Check magento log files and console log for real error. based on that you need to resolve it.
